# How to include a class as a member of another class in c++

Tags: c++

I have looked round the web and tried most of what they suggested but i still can't get my code to work. I have two classes created using `header files and .cpp files` I want to include one class in the other without using `inheritance` but i get an error.

Here is the code for the `Birthday class`:

Birthday.h:

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H


class Birthday
{
    public:
        Birthday(int m, int d, int y);
        ~Birthday();
        void printDate();

    protected:


    private:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
};

#endif // BIRTHDAY_H
```

Birthday.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"

using namespace std;

Birthday::Birthday(int m, int d, int y):month(m), day(d), year(y)
{
    //ctor
}

Birthday::~Birthday()
{
    cout << "Birthday Destructor" << endl;

}

void Birthday::printDate()
{
    cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;

}
```

Then the class that will include a `Birthday class as a member`, Person class.

Person.h:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include "Birthday.h"

class Person
{
    public:
        Person(string n, Birthday b);
        void printinfo();

    protected:

    private:
        string name;
        Birthday bd;
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Person.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Birthday.h"
#include "Person.h"


using namespace std;

Person::Person(string n, Birthday b):name(n), bd(b)
{
    //ctor

}


void Person::printinfo()
{
    cout << name << endl;
    bd.printDate();

}
```

Please note this works well when both classes are created in the same file but gives an error when used in separate header and source files.

Error messages:

```
     Person::Person(string n, Birthday b):name(n), bd(b)
 ^
In file included from /home/george/codeblock-docs/Birthday/Person.cpp:4:0:
/home/george/codeblock-docs/Birthday/Person.h:6:7: error: candidates are: constexpr Person::Person(Person&&)
 class Person
       ^
/home/george/codeblock-docs/Birthday/Person.h:6:7: error:                 constexpr Person::Person(const Person&)
/home/george/codeblock-docs/Birthday/Person.h:6:7: error:                 Person::Person()
/home/george/codeblock-docs/Birthday/Person.cpp: In member function ‘void Person::printinfo()’:
/home/george/codeblock-docs/Birthday/Person.cpp:18:13: error: ‘name’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << name << endl;
             ^
```

Sorry was away didn't see the notice of hold I hope this is more explicit.  This error showed on compiling the code

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong, but you should `#include <string>` in "Person.h". You need to add the error message (don't describe it, use copy and paste.

Comment: I'm flagging this as "unclear what you're asking" because you haven't done the basic step of telling us what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `std::` namespace specifier for `string` in your `Person.h`. You should specialize `std::string`:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(std::string n, Birthday b);
```

Comment: `using namespace` should never be done in header files because it pollutes anything else that includes said header. And you presumably mean _specify_ `std::string`, not specialise it, as the latter is a well-defined term relating to `template`s.

Comment: Agree. I've stated that there are two options and started with `std::string`. We have to show all options if we want to help.

Comment: There were 2 options, one of which is a universally discouraged shortcut that is highly likely to create new problems. We don't have to show all options, only good ones. Nice edit!

Comment: Thanks GMichael that was the issue.

Comment: If I may ask why the `-2` on my question GMichael gave me the right answer.

Comment: My guess is that you were downvoted because you said 'I get an error' but didn't bother to tell us what it was. Thanks for editing to add that in.